# Best way to pass JSON from PHP controller to AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I am working with Angular JS and Yii2. In one of my PHP controllers I need to pass an array of data from backend to front end, so I am json encoding my php array and setting a var in the view like so:

```
$script = "var projects = '".json_encode($projects)."';";
$this->view->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
```

Then in my Angular controller I am getting the JSON data like so:

```
app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', function($scope, args){
   $scope.projects;    

   $scope.init = function(){
       $scope.projects = angular.fromJson(projects);
   };

   $scope.init();
}]);
```

My question is, is this good form? Is there a right/wrong way to process data like this on page load with Angular?

Cheers

Ash

Comment: `$script = "var projects = ".json_encode($projects).";";...$scope.projects = projects;`

Comment: I am talking more about using an init method to set up data in my controller like that. Musa your amend to the code doesn't work - you can't use repeatables if json isn't imported properly.

Comment: if you don't use fromJson then you are just setting $scope.projects as a string not an array

Comment: You probably didn't notice the quotes are around json_encode is no longer there.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice. Nice approach

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like this

```
app.controller('ProjectsController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
   $scope.projects = angular.fromJson($window.projects);
```

Or use your init function method if you like, the important part is using the $window service.

Comment: Nope that won't work. I can however strip out the init method and just use a one-liner in the controller which is more elegant.

$scope.projects = angular.fromJson(projects);

Comment: Maybe it assumes that you have declared variable "projects" in global scope?   I.m. window.projects was declared somewhere on page like var projects = "{json}";. But in this case I see no reason to parse JSON - you can just declare variable as object (array or etc)